# Financial math compound

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, finance

Billy Bob, who is 22, won a prize of $5000 at McDonalds. He invests the money at
8% compounded quarterly for 43 years until he retires. When he retires, he then
reinvests the money at 7% compounded monthly and makes equal monthly
withdrawals for a further 25 years at which time the money would run out. How
much money would he get each month? Show all work

This is how I answered: 
FV = R (1+i)^n = 5000(1+0.02)^172     where i=0.08/4   and n=43*4
FV = $150729.9473

Then:
PV= P {[(1 + i)^n]- 1 / [1 + i]^n}/i    where i=0.07/12   and n = 24*12
$150729.9473 = P   {[(1 + 0.07/12)^24*12]-1 / [1+0.07/1]^24*12}/0.07/12
P=  $150729.9473 / 141.48690338
P =  $1,065.33

However the answer should be 1,044.74 . I think I am doing something wrong with the interest. I know my answer is very close to the right answer but it is still incorrect.

Comment: In your first equation, shouldn't the interest be 0.08, and not 0.02 in $R(1+i) = 5000(1+0.08)^{172}$?

Comment: In the second part, shouldn't $n=25\times 12$?

Comment: Worth noting:  your formulas are nearly unreadable. [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site.

Comment: I think you have calculated $141.48690338$ as  $\left\{  \dfrac{1-\frac 1{  [1+0.07/12]^{25*12}}}{0.07/12} \right\}$ but this is not what I think you have written

Comment: you'll have the result $1,044.74$ if $7\%$ is the effective annual interest, so that the monthly interest is $i_m=1.07^{1/12}-1\approx 0.57\%$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I´m right in total your equality was more or less

$$5000\cdot 1.02^{43\cdot 4}\cdot (1+\frac{0.07}{12})^{25\cdot 12}=P\cdot \frac{(1+0.07/12)^{25\cdot 12}-1}{\frac{0.07}{12}}$$

As [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu) has already mentioned,  it has to be $25\cdot 12$. But nevertheless I get the same result, $P=1065.33$. See here the result of the [calculator w.a](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5000*1.02%5E(43*4)*(1%2B0.07%2F12)%5E(25*12)%3Dr*((1%2B0.07%2F12)%5E(25*12)-1)%2F(0.07%2F12)). And I agree with your calculation. I don´t see any mistake.

---

After testing other variations I´ve found out that they have used the $\texttt{effective interest rate}$ (aka equivalent interest rate) for the $7\%$.

To get the equivalent interest rate one has to solve the fowing equation

$\left(1+\frac{i}{12} \right)^{12}=1.07 \Rightarrow i=(1.07^{1/12}-1)\cdot 12=0.06784974465$

If you replace $0.07$ by the equivalent interest rate you´ll get the desired solution: [calculator w.a](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5000*1.02%5E(43*4)*(1%2B0.06784974465%2F12)%5E(25*12)-r*((1%2B0.06784974465%2F12)%5E(25*12)-1)%2F(0.06784974465%2F12)%3D0). I think a little less number of digits is sufficient.